# Gstreamer. PCM streaming

Tags: gstreamer

I have a pcm audio file that I want to stream via rtp. When I do

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=AudioRaw515151.pcm ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, channels=1, layout=interleaved, rate=8000 ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.2.5 port=5010
```

I have that kind of message

```
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.019270487
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

But I can play this audio, That means that audio is ok.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=AudioRaw515151.pcm ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, channels=1, layout=interleaved, rate=8000 ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! rtppcmdepay ! alawdec ! audiosink
```

I tried to take another file-avi file, take audio from it and maked the same thing

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.avi ^
    ! qtdemux name=mux^
    ! queue ^
    ! faad ^
    ! audioconvert ^
    ! audioresample ^
    ! "audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)8000" ^
    ! alawenc ^
    ! rtppcmapay ^
        ! queue ^
        ! udpsink host=192.168.2.5 port=5010
```

As you see, this the same thing but with audio from avi. Everything works.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

When I open Wireshark I see that when I run my pipeline with PCM, it fires all data without any delay and in every packet that I send is:

```
Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x40b5 (may be caused by "IP checksum offload"?)]
Message: Bad checksum
```

So here is a question. I think that I have a problem with timestamps  or something like that, when I do !alawenc (encoding to G711), I am right?
And what solution can  fix that problem?

Comment: I have receive video but not audio what i miss?

Answer (score 1):

First Question. Does the 2nd example play?

A few more comments:

- file.avi and qtdemux sounds wrong, just use decodebin (or uridecodebin) to leave the pligging to gstreamer.
- for raw audio I recommend to use the audioparse element

And finally there are a bunch of rtp examples in the git repo:
https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp/client-PCMA.sh

Comment: >>First Question. Does the 2nd example play? Yes
Thank you. Will try now

Comment: What I found : filesrc will read the data from the given file as raw bytes; I cannot just encode these raw bytes with alawenc. So I add !audioparse  after file src, and output is
`ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioParse:audioparse0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstrawparse.c(471): gst_raw_parse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioParse:audioparse0`